# Asp.net with ajax vs. Silverlight (or.. learn ajax or Ssilverlight)

Tags: ajax, silverlight

I already know Asp.net and C#. I want to build web site, and I need to choose between learning Silverlight or learning Ajax.

The site will be (visual) with nice tables and a little graphics, and with hard work with db.

My question is what is the recommended way for me, and the reasons.

Thank u and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's current position would indicate that you should go with Asp.Net + HTML + CSS + jQuery (I would use MVC as it gives you much better control as to what gets rendered in the page, but that's just a recommendation).

http://mashable.com/2010/10/29/microsoft-silverlgiht-html/

Even if we ignore all the news regarding this shift from SilverLight to what's commonly being called "HTML5", learning & using jQuery + HTML + CSS has several advantages:

- From a personal standpoint, all the knowledge you'll get will be useful for C# and for any other languages you need to use in the future for developing web apps.
- Using Silverlight (or flash) you are basically telling search engines to ignore you. Ok, maybe it's not so radical, but you'll have a hard time trying to make your page climb positions in Google & Bing, if you intend to do so.
- Silverlight makes you depend on a browser plugin. Your page won't work in any OS or browser that doesn't have the plugin installed.
- You'll find much more information and documentation for jQuery + HTML than for Silverlight, as jQuery is used not only with C#, but also with PHP, Java...

As a benefit of using Silverlight, however, you will gain the ability to stream DRM'd content (it's actually Silverlight's and Flash's main strength right now). How useful that will be to you, I don't know.

Comment: Thank u about the ןnvested answer. But what about the option that I offer - Ajax?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. There's no Ajax as in "learning Ajax". It basically only refers to the ability to request asynchronous data (load data without refreshing the browser). I mean, you can learn how to do it in plain js, but it's just one line of code if you use a library. If you want to use ajax, and create nice and interactive pages, what you need to learn to use is one of the Js libraries (that among other things use Ajax), such as jQuery (there are others such as MooTools, YUI, Dojo, Prototype, but jQuery is maybe the best, and it's supported by MS in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

The question promotes somewhat subjective answers, so please understand that the answers will vary from person to person.

I would prefer AJAX in this instance.  If you need to do a lot of animation then silverlight is probably your best bet.  However, if you're looking just to display tabular data (with some graphics), the most commonly used approach (by my observation) is to use AJAX to populate tabular data.

The most common use I see for Silverlight these days is media streaming and proof of concepts.